# xcodebuild far slower than Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, build, xcodebuild

Building from the command line with xcodebuild is orders of magnitude slower than building the same project, same scheme, same target from within Xcode.  Does anyone know why this might be the case and how I might speed up my xcodebuild build?

I'm invoking xcodebuild as follows:

```
xcodebuild -scheme <SCHEME> -workspace <WORKSPACE> -configuration Debug -sdk iphonesimulator7.0 -jobs 12 build
```

for building on a  12-core Mac Pro.  I guessed at the -jobs setting but it seems reasonable.  Does anyone have any advice?  Is there a way, by analyzing Xcode's build log, to tell what settings for xcodebuild most closely map to what Xcode itself is using?  Thanks!

Comment: have you figure this out?

Comment: I have the same issue. The only thing I could imagine is optimization level, but they are both using -O3.

Answer (score 1):

While this alone may not explain the slowness of xcodebuild compared to IDE, I've seen some improvements if I disable Spotlight indexing on `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` directory.

Comment: This should not have any effect since spotlight by default does not index `~/Library` at all (apart from Apple Mail data)

Answer (score -1):

When using `xcodebuild test` that will reboot the simulator each time. It is the main reason case the xcodebuild slowly. When you using xcode test directly, The simulator will not boot twice after booted.

You can try this:

```
xcodebuild -project Example.xcodeproj \
    -scheme ExampleTests \
    -disable-concurrent-destination-testing \
    -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 13' \
    -sdk iphonesimulator \
    CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED="NO" \
    test
```

1. `-disable-concurrent-destination-testing` disable clone simulator in Xcode 14 and test in the same simulator
2. `CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED="NO"` disable signing test target will faster